# Printing results from python functions with VS code

Tags: python, pandas, function, visual-studio-code, printing

I am trying to reproduce the results from this webpage:

" https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-grid-search-triple-exponential-smoothing-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/ "

But after running on VS code I get the result "done" instead of the results that should be printed.
The complete code is:

```
# grid search ets models for monthly car sales
from math import sqrt
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from joblib import Parallel
from joblib import delayed
from warnings import catch_warnings
from warnings import filterwarnings
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import array
 
# one-step Holt Winter’s Exponential Smoothing forecast
def exp_smoothing_forecast(history, config):
    t,d,s,p,b,r = config
    # define model
    history = array(history)
    model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p)
    # fit model
    model_fit = model.fit(optimized=True, use_boxcox=b, remove_bias=r)
    # make one step forecast
    yhat = model_fit.predict(len(history), len(history))
    return yhat[0]
 
# root mean squared error or rmse
def measure_rmse(actual, predicted):
    return sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, predicted))
 
# split a univariate dataset into train/test sets
def train_test_split(data, n_test):
    return data[:-n_test], data[-n_test:]
 
# walk-forward validation for univariate data
def walk_forward_validation(data, n_test, cfg):
    predictions = list()
    # split dataset
    train, test = train_test_split(data, n_test)
    # seed history with training dataset
    history = [x for x in train]
    # step over each time-step in the test set
    for i in range(len(test)):
        # fit model and make forecast for history
        yhat = exp_smoothing_forecast(history, cfg)
        # store forecast in list of predictions
        predictions.append(yhat)
        # add actual observation to history for the next loop
        history.append(test[i])
    # estimate prediction error
    error = measure_rmse(test, predictions)
    return error
 
# score a model, return None on failure
def score_model(data, n_test, cfg, debug=False):
    result = None
    # convert config to a key
    key = str(cfg)
    # show all warnings and fail on exception if debugging
    if debug:
        result = walk_forward_validation(data, n_test, cfg)
    else:
        # one failure during model validation suggests an unstable config
        try:
            # never show warnings when grid searching, too noisy
            with catch_warnings():
                filterwarnings("ignore")
                result = walk_forward_validation(data, n_test, cfg)
        except:
            error = None
    # check for an interesting result
    if result is not None:
        print(' > Model[%s] %.3f' % (key, result))
    return (key, result)
 
# grid search configs
def grid_search(data, cfg_list, n_test, parallel=True):
    scores = None
    if parallel:
        # execute configs in parallel
        executor = Parallel(n_jobs=cpu_count(), backend='multiprocessing')
        tasks = (delayed(score_model)(data, n_test, cfg) for cfg in cfg_list)
        scores = executor(tasks)
    else:
        scores = [score_model(data, n_test, cfg) for cfg in cfg_list]
    # remove empty results
    scores = [r for r in scores if r[1] != None]
    # sort configs by error, asc
    scores.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    return scores
 
# create a set of exponential smoothing configs to try
def exp_smoothing_configs(seasonal=[None]):
    models = list()
    # define config lists
    t_params = ['add', 'mul', None]
    d_params = [True, False]
    s_params = ['add', 'mul', None]
    p_params = seasonal
    b_params = [True, False]
    r_params = [True, False]
    # create config instances
    for t in t_params:
        for d in d_params:
            for s in s_params:
                for p in p_params:
                    for b in b_params:
                        for r in r_params:
                            cfg = [t,d,s,p,b,r]
                            models.append(cfg)
    return models
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load dataset
    series = read_csv('monthly-car-sales.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
    data = series.values
    # data split
    n_test = 12
    # model configs
    cfg_list = exp_smoothing_configs(seasonal=[0,6,12])
    # grid search
    scores = grid_search(data[:,0], cfg_list, n_test)
    print('done')
    # list top 3 configs
    for cfg, error in scores[:3]:
        print(cfg, error)
```

I have tried executing the function bellow, but did not work as well.

`exp_smoothing_configs(seasonal=[None])`

It could be something really simple since I am new to coding. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `scores` is empty, add a log trace to check it: `print('Scores length:', len(scores)) `

Comment: It returns me " Scores length: 0 "

Comment: Then, check previous variables used in the process:  `data`,  `cfg_list`, ...

Comment: I have checked and data and cfg_list are ok, they are not empty. So I do not know why the score is empty

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not vs code issue, it is an old code issue.
ExponentialSmoothing has been updated since this code was written.
damped is deprecated and now should use damped_trend.
and it also accept use_boxcox as a parameter (and not in model.fit)

so replace

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p)
# fit model
model_fit = model.fit(optimized=True, use_boxcox=b, remove_bias=r)
```

with

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped_trend=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p, use_boxcox=b)
# fit model
model_fit = model.fit(optimized=True, remove_bias=r)
```

Also, seasonal_periods is not accepting values less than or equal to 1. so when you call exp_smoothing_configs, consider replacing the 0 value in the list.

Comment: I have done the suggested changes, but it returns the same as before. No changes in the outcome

Comment: What version is your statsmodel package? (I'm using 0.13.2)

Comment: I have the same version 0.13.2

Comment: I believe the problem is with the score, because the array "scores" is empty, and so nothing is printed in the end. But I donnot know why the score generated is empty
 " scores = grid_search(data[:,0], cfg_list, n_test) " generates a empty df.

Comment: I got score empty as well, then I've start to follow where score is coming from and it seems that score_model returns None for the result. result is None because walk_forward_validation is breaking when calling exp_smoothing_forecast.
exp_smoothing_forecast is breaking when calling model.fit.
model.fit is breaking (on my computer) because trying to set the value for use_boxcox.
When I moved use_boxcox to ExponentialSmoothing, the problem was solved (on my computer)

Comment: Can you tell me which part of the code you changed? I did not understand which change was made

Comment: I've changed the exp_smoothing_forecast function replacing both model and model_fit

Comment: So you replaced  ``` model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped_trend=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p,use_boxcox=b) ```          
for  ```model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped_trend=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p,ExponentialSmoothing=b) ``` ?

Comment: No I changed to model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped_trend=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p, use_boxcox=b)

Comment: and model_fit = model.fit(optimized=True, remove_bias=r)

Comment: I have tried the same, but for me nothing changed on the results

Comment: I suggest that you move the block in score_model function out of the try block so you can follow the errors (the try block is skipping errors) ___  this block --->            with catch_warnings():
                filterwarnings("ignore")
                result = walk_forward_validation(data, n_test, cfg)
___